# What is the real example of SetSessionStateBehavior method in ASP.NET 4.0?

Tags: asp.net

In ASP.NET 4.0 there is new method HttpContext.SetSessionStateBehavior by which we can change the session state at run time. But what is the real example in application development where we need to use this method?

Answer (score 2):

Before 4.0 there were only two ways to disable session state.

- Application Level in Web.Config
- Page Level using Page directive

If your application dynamically generates the pages based on query string then you didn't have a way to selectively disable session state for some pages for improved performance. In that cause you would just disable for all pages or enable for all pages.

With this you can write a http module that can intercept the request, look at the query string or path of the url and disable/enable the session state.